# how can we access flows text Template's variable in apex code ? In body how can i access the variable of flow?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocablevariable, text-template

I have to post chatter through the flow as text template. When chatter is posted I need to set CreatedById as Customer_success_manager__c, so that I write apexcode, now how can I use that text Template in code. how can I set text template 'isStatusEscalated' as post.body = {isStatusEscalated} in the code. if(op.Status__c == 'Escalated'){ FeedItem post = new FeedItem(); post.Body={!StatusIsEscalated}; post.CreatedById = op.Customer_success_manager__c; –

```
public class PostChatter {
@InvocableMethod(label='Chatter Sender as Customer Success Manager ' description='Change chatter Sender name username to customer sucess manager ' category='Opportunity') 
public static void postFeed(list<opportunity> oppID)
{
    List<Opportunity> opp = [select id, name, Status__c, Customer_success_manager__c, OwnerId from Opportunity where id=:oppID];
    List<FeedItem> fi = new List<FeedItem>();
    system.debug('opp'+opp);
    for(Opportunity op : opp)
    {
        if(op.Status__c == 'Escalated'){
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.ParentId = op.id;
            post.Body={!StatusIsEscalated};
            post.CreatedById = op.Customer_success_manager__c;
            fi.add(post);
        }
        system.debug('');
        if (op.Status__c <> 'Escalated')
        {
            
        }
    }
           insert fi;
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an InvocableVariable:

```
public class Inputs {
  @InvocableVariable(label='Opportunity Id' required=true) Id opportunityId;
  @InvocableVariable(label='Message' required=true) String message;
}
```

Which then goes in place of the current parameter:

```
public static void postFeed(Request[] inputs) {
  Id[] opportunityIds = new Id[0];
  for(Request input: inputs) {
    opportunityIds.add(input.opportunityId);
  }
  Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
    select name, Status__c, Customer_success_manager__c, OwnerId 
    from Opportunity 
    where id = :opportunityIds
  ]);
  for(Integer index = 0, size = inputs.size(); index < size; index++) {
    Request input = inputs[index];
    Opportunity opportunityRecord = opportunities.get(input.opportunityId);
    // etc
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to post chatter through the flow as text template. When chatter is posted I need to set CreatedById as Customer_success_manager__c, so that I write apexcode, now how can I use that text Template in code.  how can I set text template 'isStatusEscalated' as post.body = {isStatusEscalated} in the code.                                                                            
     if(op.Status__c == 'Escalated'){
         FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.Body={!StatusIsEscalated};
            post.CreatedById = op.Customer_success_manager__c;

Comment: I don't have variable in the flow